# Add cell from multiple spreadsheets in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains 30 sheets (each day for the month of September). I want to add cell K36 from each sheet, but I don’t know how. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

IF your sheets are numbered 1 to 30 inclusive (eg up to Sheet30), it may be less tedious to insert:

```
=indirect("Sheet"&column()&"!K36")
```

into ColumnA (say Row10), copy that across to AD, then add that row (say `=sum(10:10)` ) - or do this on a separate sheet and reference the result from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

=Sheet1!K36 + Sheet2!K36 + Sheet3!K36 + Sheet4!K36 + Sheet5!K36 + Sheet6!K36 + Sheet7!K36 + Sheet8!K36    etc

There are other answers based on scripting, which you should investigate if you need a repeatable solution (hint - search for 3D summing).   But this will be the quickest approach for a one-off.

Comment: Mary, I went ahead and approved the edit as it seemed as if you had a typo, but feel free to make any adjustments as you see fit.